# How to use stack to produce multiple columns data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, stack

I want to convert a list of lists into a `data.frame`. First I each sublist was only of length 1 and so I used `stack(as.data.frame(...))` but stack does not seam to be able to produce multicolumns `data.frame`. So what it the best way to achieve that:

```
# works fine with only sublists of length 1
 l = list(a = sample(1:5, 5), b = sample(1:5, 5))
> stack(as.data.frame(l))
   values ind
1       5   a
2       4   a
3       1   a
4       2   a
5       3   a
6       2   b
7       1   b
8       3   b
9       5   b
10      4   b
```

Now my list is a list of lists:

```
l = list(a = list(first = sample(1:5, 5), sec = sample(1:5, 5)), b = list(first = sample(1:5, 5), sec = sample(1:5, 5)))
stack(as.data.frame(l))
   values     ind
1       4 a.first
2       5 a.first
3       3 a.first
4       1 a.first
5       2 a.first
6       3   a.sec
7       5   a.sec
8       1   a.sec
9       2   a.sec
10      4   a.sec
11      5 b.first
12      4 b.first
13      3 b.first
14      1 b.first
15      2 b.first
16      3   b.sec
17      4   b.sec
18      1   b.sec
19      2   b.sec
20      5   b.sec
```

while I'd like to have still a column `ind` with `a` and `b` and two columns `first` and `sec`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can flatten the `list` by concatenating (`c`) the nested elements ('l1'), get the substring from the `names` of 'l1' ('nm1' and 'nm2'), `split` the 'l1' by 'nm1' (i.e. substring obtained by removing the prefix) while we set the `names` of 'l1' with 'nm2' (substring obtained by removing suffix starting with `.`), loop through the `list` and `stack` it ('lst').  Then, we `cbind` the 'ind' column (which is the same in all the `list` elements so we get it from the first list element - `lst[[1]][2]`) with the 'value' column i.e. the first column.

```
l1 <- do.call(c, l)
nm1 <- sub("[^.]+\\.", "", names(l1))
nm2 <- sub("\\..*", "", names(l1))
lst <- lapply(split(setNames(l1, nm2), nm1), stack)
cbind(lst[[1]][2],lapply(lst, `[[`, 1))
#   ind first sec
#1    a     1   1
#2    a     5   5
#3    a     4   4
#4    a     3   3
#5    a     2   2
#6    b     3   4
#7    b     4   5
#8    b     2   2
#9    b     1   3
#10   b     5   1
```

---

Or using `dplyr/purrr` we can get the expected output.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
l1 <- transpose(l)
n1 <- names(l1)
l1 %>%
   map(stack) %>%
    bind_cols %>%
    setNames(., make.unique(names(.))) %>%
    select(ind, matches("value")) %>% 
    setNames(., c("ind", n1))
#      ind first   sec
#   (fctr) (int) (int)
#1       a     1     1
#2       a     5     5
#3       a     4     4
#4       a     3     3
#5       a     2     2
#6       b     3     4
#7       b     4     5
#8       b     2     2
#9       b     1     3
#10      b     5     1
```

Comment: ok comments deleted, it's work indeed even if each sublist has more than two entries (here `first` and `sec`). thanks

Comment: @clemlaflemme  Thanks for the update.  I added one more method that would make it more flexible

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
df <- stack(as.data.frame(l))
# split names of variables
indVars <- strsplit(as.character(df$ind), split="\\.")
# add variables to data.frame
df$letters <- sapply(indVars, function(i) i[1])
df$order <- sapply(indVars, function(i) i[2])

# get final data.frame
cbind("order"=unstack(df, letters~order)[,1], unstack(df, values~order))
```